# On a Google Sheets, is there a way to trigger a Google Script function from a standalone webpage <button>?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've created a small electron app that shows data from a google sheet via sheetrock.js to display table data. I've added a form that submits data to the google sheet with the help of [triblondon's git](https://gist.github.com/triblondon/854315a40d280a22fd89804e332fd7b3)

Now I'm trying to Implement a simple button on the electron app that will move populated rows from one sheet to another, creating a history. But for the life of me, I can't find a method of doing so that doesn't involve sending json data like the method above, writing to a cell and just doing formulas from there.

I'm just looking for a simpler, more direct approach by just invoking a function on the google script side (button + javascript probably).

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy your script as apps script. You will have use the public **URL** to be triggered by your button.

You can check everything about it on the [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) documentation.